# WCF Asynchronous 'End' method not called after upgrading .NET

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, upgrade

We have an application (console application "server" self hosting a bunch of WCF services and a few WPF clients) written in .NET 3.5.  I wanted to have a go at upgrading the "server" app to .NET 4.6.  For testing I was just going to change the runtime and add some child projects in 4.6, leaving the rest of the projects at 3.5. In the top level project I changed the target to 4.6 and made sure the app.config file had this in it:

```
<startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
  <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.6"/>
</startup>
```

The WCF services and other support projects are in the solution and I did not modify them in anyway.

I also did not modify the WPF client.

In some of our services we implement the asynchronous begin/end pattern *on the server*.  This is new to me as I learned WCF with the async/await pattern (though I'm familiar with begin/end in general).  Any asynchronous requirements on the client are left up to the calling code.

**Service**

```
public interface IMyServiceCallback
{
    void UnrelatedNotifyClientsMethod(Notification message);
}



[ServiceContract(CallbackContract = typeof(IMyServiceCallback))]
public interface IMyService
{
    // ...

    [OperationContract(AsyncPattern = true)]
    IAsyncResult BeginFetchSomething(int howMany, AsyncCallback callback, object state);
    FetchSomethingResult EndFetchSomething(IAsyncResult result);

    // ...
}



[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single, ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Multiple)]
public class MyService : IMyService
{
    // ...

    [PermissionSetAttribute(SecurityAction.LinkDemand, Name = "FullTrust")]
    public IAsyncResult BeginFetchSomething(int howMany, AsyncCallback callback, object state)
    {
        AsyncResult<FetchSomethingResult> something = new AsyncResult<FetchSomethingResult>(callback, state);

        BackgroundWorker backgroundWorker = new BackgroundWorker();
        backgroundWorker.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler((sender, args) =>
        {
            try
            {
                FetchSomethingResult resultData = Database.FetchSomethingQuery(howMany);
                something.Result = resultData;
                something.Complete(true);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Log(e);
                something.HandleException(e, false);
            }
            backgroundWorker.Dispose();
        });

        backgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync();
        return something;
    }


    public FetchSomethingResult EndFetchSomething(IAsyncResult result)
    {
        AsyncResult<FetchSomethingResult> something = result as AsyncResult<FetchSomethingResult>;
        something.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne();
        return something.Result;
    }

    // ...

    // other similar methods

    // ...

}



public class AsyncResult : IAsyncResult
{

    // ...

    public void Complete(bool completedSynchronously)
    {
        lock (this.Mutex)
        {
            this.IsCompleted = true;
            this.CompletedSynchronously = completedSynchronously;
        }
        this.SignalCompletion();
    }

    protected void SignalCompletion()
    {
        (this.AsyncWaitHandle as ManualResetEvent).Set();
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(d => { this.InvokeCallback(); });
    }

    protected void InvokeCallback()
    {
        if (this.Callback != null)
        {
            this.Callback(this);
        }
    }

    public void HandleException(Exception e, bool completedSynchronously)
    {
        lock (this.Mutex)
        {
            this.IsCompleted = true;
            this.CompletedSynchronously = completedSynchronously;
            this.Exception = e;
        }
        this.SignalCompletion();
    }

    // ...
}
```

**Client** (As generated by Visual Studio "Add Service Reference")

```
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.ServiceModel", "4.0.0.0")]
public partial class MyServiceClient : System.ServiceModel.DuplexClientBase<NameSpace.ServiceClients.IMyServiceClient>, NameSpace.ServiceClients.IMyServiceCliene
{
    // ...

    public NameSpace.ServiceClients.FetchSomethingResult FetchSomething(int howMany)
    {
        return base.Channel.FetchSomething(howMany);
    }

    // ...

}
```

On the client we have a few generic classes that wrap and expose our services, calls can happen on the main thread but usually are on background threads via background workers.  By simply upgrading the server app from .NET 3.5 to 4+ and not making any changes, the End methods on the server are no longer called.  I've confirmed that the Begin methods return and that the workers call .Complete() and invoke the callback, but nothing happens after that.  After 1 minute the client will throw a timeout exception on the call.

Our codebase is fairly large and complex and I wasn't expecting any changes in behaviour after reading the .NET 4 migration notes.

**EDIT:** I've included a screenshot of the microsoft service trace utility showing the same call to FetchProductVersion before the update (top, 3.5) and after (bottom, 4.6).

[image: WCF async pattern end method not called]

**EDIT 2/3:** The failures seem inconsistent in some cases.

Comment: This may be obvious but have you confirmed you're not running into cross-thread ownership issue? in 3.5 this would result in warning and things kept working (or at least that's how i remember my winform days) in .net 4+ it's an exception in best case and dead like this in worst. Have you tried explicitly getting a wait handle on your IAsyncResult & then getting the result? if that works, you're more than likely running into cross-thread issues i'd imagine. Since this is WPF, dispatcher doesn't play well with Background threads; be sure to try manual Invokes on dispatcher to see it helps.

Comment: Also while this isn't wpf specific - we do have some very knowledgable folks in [WPF Chat channel](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18165/wpf): come join us for a discussion since comments are rather limited place for such a thing. You may also have luck in C# chat channel for discussion over this. Without an MCVE, this is very difficult to answer and more than likely will have a wasted bounty and possibly put on-hold (since this categorises as Debug help question that requires MCVE with it)

Comment: @Maverik I had suspected cross thread issues after seeing the graph from the trace utility, I'll most likely be attempting to investigate that today. And I was secretly hoping this was some known issue with the upgrade - but now I see it may be hard to answer. Ill swing by the chat as well, thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must properly set [`IAsyncResult.CompletedSynchronously`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.iasyncresult.completedsynchronously%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) property to `false` because you complete `IAsyncResult` in asynchronous manner. In contrary to WCF in .NET Framework 4.6, WCF in .NET Framework 3.5 just ignores it in this case.

So change `something.Complete(true);` to `something.Complete(completedSynchronously: false);`.

You can check who and when uses `IAsyncResult.CompletedSynchronously` by placing a breakpoint in it's getter:

```
bool _completedSynchronously = false;
public bool CompletedSynchronously
{
    get
    {
        // Set breakpoint here.
        return _completedSynchronously;
    }
    set
    {
        _completedSynchronously = value;
    }
}
```

If you launch WCF service using .NET Framework 3.5 you will notice that it is never actually called. So older version of WCF simply ignores it. If you launch service using .NET Framework 4.6 you will see that it is used quite a lot by WCF internal class `DispatchOperationRuntime`. By [`InvokeBegin()`](https://github.com/dotnet/wcf/blob/c975ecc239947c3bd4a3d3402d8a81bf41f3c9a2/src/System.Private.ServiceModel/src/System/ServiceModel/Dispatcher/DispatchOperationRuntime.cs#L213) and [`InvokeCallback()`](https://github.com/dotnet/wcf/blob/c975ecc239947c3bd4a3d3402d8a81bf41f3c9a2/src/System.Private.ServiceModel/src/System/ServiceModel/Dispatcher/DispatchOperationRuntime.cs#L256) functions in particular.

Comment: This did it! I was able to confirm with testing our application - and I added the breakpoint on the getter for CompletedSynchronouslyand confirmed access between both runtime versions is what you predicted it would be. I'm not sure why we had it true in the first place, but I'm more than happy to change it.  Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I see two low-hanging items you should validate before digging very deeply.

1. Validate that the async begin and end methods have the same suffix names.

> WCF automatically routes inbound messages to the Begin< methodName> method and routes the results of the End< methodName> call to the outbound message.

In your pseudo code they do not follow the above naming convention:

> ```
> IAsyncResult BeginFetchSomething(int howMany, AsyncCallback callback, object state);
> FetchSomethingResult EndFetchJobResults(IAsyncResult result);
> ```

2. Validate you are decorating your methods appropriately. MSDN provides the following example:

   ```
   [OperationContract (AsyncPattern=true)]
   IAsyncResult BeginAdd(int a, int b, AsyncCallback cb, AsyncState s);//async begin

   [OperationContract]
   int EndAdd(IAsyncResult r);//async end

   [OperationContract]
   int Add(int a, int b);//synchronous complete action
   ```

In your pseudo code the OperationContract attributes are missing. Hopefully it is this simple. Good Luck!

[MSDN Source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.operationcontractattribute.asyncpattern(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Apologies - the mistmatch was my mistakes when trimming down our code into the pseudo code.  Also, [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/how-to-implement-an-asynchronous-service-operation) suggests the OperationContract attribute only needs to be on the Begin method - which is what we had working before with 3.5 - is that not correct?

Comment: In my excitement I forgot to include my source. I've added it to the post. I didn't spin up a working service, so I am not certain about the attributes not being required. I'm suspicious of everything until I've tried it myself.